# Test java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I try to write a simple tests for my project(it is my first test, so don't judge me harshly), but my test failed and I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productsRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#251f7d26' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#251f7d26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#251f7d26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 52 more
```

Applicationtest.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fruitshop?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

I write a tests for two controllers.
My Tests:

```
import com.Products.Products;
import org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTest.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

public class ProductsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void addNewProduct() {
        Products product = new Products();
        product.setName("Orange");
        product.setPrice(121);
        ResponseEntity<Products> postResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity("/products/addProduct", product, Products.class);
        assertNotNull(postResponse);
        assertNotNull(postResponse.getBody());
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllProducts() {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, httpHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("/products/allProducts",
                HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        assertNotNull(response.getBody());
    }
}
```

This is my controller I use mysql:

```
package com.Products;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/products")
public class ProductsController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductsRepository productsRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addNewProduct (@RequestParam (value = "name")  String NameOfFruit,
                                               @RequestParam  (value = "price") int PriceOfProduct) {
        Products product = new Products();
        product.setName(NameOfFruit);
        product.setPrice(PriceOfProduct);

        productsRepository.save(product);
        return "Done";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allProducts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Products> getAllProducts() {
        return productsRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Week9</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
        <spring.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <plagins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plagins>

</project>
```

ApplicationTest:

```
package com.Products;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTest {
}
```

I don 't know what to do anymore. Please indicate what the problem is and how I can solve it

Worked version: https://github.com/Asel06/Neobis-Tasks/tree/master/task-9/Week9

Comment: Can you show your ApplicationTest as well? And indicate which version of Spring Boot you are using?
EntityManagerFactory is a JPA interface. It's usually auto-configured by spring boot, but you're probably missing some annotation or something similar in ApplicationTest.

Comment: 1. Your dependencies are a mess, 2. delete `ApplicationTest` and just add a clean `@SpringBootTest` to your testclass.

Comment: @Asel what do you use jetty,jboss,tomcat or what? also do you use jsp or what

Comment: Because you have everything into your pom.xml

Comment: Is there specific reason that you need embeded jetty enstead of tomcat?

Comment: @Nonika No reason.  It's just that when I was writing the test I started making mistakes and to fix them I started googling and doing everything that i met

Comment: So embedded tomcat is ok for you?

Comment: Also are you using jsp?

Comment: @Nonika  Tomcat is ok, for the test I need to connect to my database and test the api so if it is better to use other tools for this, so it's ok

Comment: You should correct your pom.xml there are duplicated dependencies and lots of unneeded ones you can start from https://start.spring.io/ to generate correct project

Comment: @Nonika I did all what i can and [what is happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808292/unsatisfied-dependency-expressed-through-field-port-failed-to-convert-value-of/60809312#60809312)

Comment: @Asel can you be more specific. what is your current situation

Comment: @Nonika I made some changes (add .properties for test, you can see changes in my question ) and after this i have the error: ``` org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8080/products/addProduct": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect```  How i can change the port ? Or fix this problem

Comment: can you upload your project on github?

Comment: @Nonika Yep  [Github](https://github.com/Asel06/Neobis-Tasks/tree/master/task-9/Week9)

Comment: @Asel I have added pullrequest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `class=ApplicationTest.class` because of this your `@SpringBootTest` doesn't scan for other `@Configuration`  classes

> The component classes to use for loading an ApplicationContext. Can
>   also be specified using `@ContextConfiguration(classes=...).` If no
>   explicit classes are defined the test will look for nested
>   `@Configuration` classes, before falling back to a
>   `@SpringBootConfiguration` search.

Comment: You mean @ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationTest.class)    If you mean this, it's doesn't work

Comment: can you post your build.gradle or pom.xml?

Comment: and post also ApplicationTest.class

Comment: @Asel See pull request

Comment: I adore you!  Seriously.

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @Asel what happened in the pull request?

Comment: @hanbin615 https://github.com/Asel06/Neobis-Tasks/tree/master/task-9/Week9

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be this:

```
No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Look this up in your configs. Maybe the Config of this bean has a profile switch and only is available in the prod profile?